# How do I extract the prefix (/64) of an ipv6 address in C#?

Tags: c#, ipv6

Given an ipv6 address like "xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx", how do I extract the prefix portion (/64) in C#.

Comment: I don't see a /64 in your example....just lots of kisses!

Comment: haha. Those are not kisses ofcourse. Consider it as an ipv6 global unicast address. something like "1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234". so, given this sample as an IPAddress object in c#, what is an efficient way to extract the network prefix? (which happens to be the /64 part)

Answer (score 2):

When you say `Given an ipv6 address` I assume you have an object of the type [`IPAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx) which holds your IPv6-address.

According to the above linked documentation of `IPAddress`, it has a method [`GetAddressBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which gives you a `byte[]` containing all the bytes of the stored address. Now, given your prefix (/64) in bit and knowing that 1 byte = 8 bit we can construct the following:

```
//using System.Net

IPAddress address; //I assume it is initialized correctly
int prefix = 64;

//check if it is an IPv6-address
if (address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
{
  //and copy the prefix-bytes
  byte[] prefixBytes = new byte[prefix/8];
  Array.Copy(address.GetAddressBytes(), prefixBytes, prefix/8);
  //now the array contains the (in this example 8) prefix bytes
}
```

For a simple, visual test you may print this out to your console:

```
for (int i = 0; i < prefixBytes.Length; i++)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0)
    Console.Write(":");

  Console.Write(prefixBytes[i].ToString("X2").ToLower());
}
```